# Rank by maximum bm25 score on a field of type array<string>

Tags: vespa

I have a schema that has a field of type `array<string>`:

```
field titles type array<string> { 
        indexing: index | summary | attribute
        index: enable-bm25
        attribute: fast-search
}
```

Say `titles` contains `N` titles - `Title 1`, `Title 2`, ..., `Title N`. I would like to rank documents based on the max bm25 between one of the titles in `titles` and the query. In other words I would like the rank of the document to be equal to `max(bm25('Title 1'),bm25('Title 2'),...,bm25('Title N'))`

Just setting the ranking expression to `bm25(titles)` does not achieve what I want. For e.g. given a query `Q` with terms: `term 1, term 2, term 3` and two documents:

- doc 1: `{"titles": [".\*term 1.\*", ".\*term 1.\*", ".\*term 1.\*", ".\*term 1.\*"]}`
- doc 2: `{"titles": [".\*term 1 term 2 term 3.\*", STRING_WITH_NONE_OF_THE_TERMS, STRING_WITH_NONE_OF_THE_TERMS, STRING_WITH_NONE_OF_THE_TERMS, STRING_WITH_NONE_OF_THE_TERMS]`

Having the `bm25(titles)` ranking expression ranks `doc 1` higher than `doc 2`. I assume it's because a term from the query is in all titles, while in the second doc a term from the query is only in one title. I want `doc 2` to be ranked higher as it contains a title that is an almost complete match for the query, so max(bm25) should be higher for `doc 2` but average/sum over all docs might be higher for `doc 1`

Is there a way I can achieve that in Vespa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the detailed question. Vespa does not support this for the `bm25` rank feature. It is computed over all elements.

You can achieve similar functionality using rank-features designed for multi-valued fields. See https://docs.vespa.ai/en/searching-multi-valued-fields.html, https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/rank-features.html#features-for-indexed-multivalue-string-fields.

Unrelated: Note that unless you want to group on this field, you don't want to use `attribute` as it puts everything in memory.

```
field titles type array<string> { 
        indexing: index | summary 
        index: enable-bm25
}
```

Comment: We plan on implementing richer support for multi-valued string fields by returning allowing to return per element features as a tensor instead of an aggregate https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/29549